# Vagrant with Docker set up in Windows - Permisson denied error during rsync

Tags: vagrant-windows

I had set up a vagrant VM with boot2docker for a helloworld docker image on my windows machine. After setting it up, I wanted to sync my host machine windows folder to vm machine. As per instructions, I installed cygwin64 to get rsync on my windows machine.

After setting it up, I tried vagrant up again and I get the following permission denied error during rsync between two machines.

Do I need to set up any permissions on my vm machine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it without changing any permissions.

try this:

1) Open the file located at `$cygwin_install_location/etc/fstab`

2) replace the last line with `none / cygdrive binary 0 0`

(This removes the /cygwin/-prefix in its path)

and:

1) edit `$vagrant_install_location\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.0\plugins\synced_folders\rsync\helper.rb`

2) remove the following lines (77-79)

```
"-o ControlMaster=auto " +
"-o ControlPath=#{controlpath} " +
"-o ControlPersist=10m " +
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I added both those changes and did vagrant reload and I still get the same error. I hope reload is good enough or am I still missing something else?

Comment: I would try a vagrant destroy & up, but i think it wouldn't matter. The official boot2docker box isn't very supportive with ssh.

Try using the boot2docker version of https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box if problems stay occuring!

Also, did u select to install openssh with cygwin?